# Is it possible to fire multiple ajax requests asynchronously in Magento 2 backend?

Tags: magento2, backend, ajax

What the title says. Im trying to run an import script with AJAX "call 1" and I want to keep track of the import (for feedback purposes) with AJAX "call 2". To give the end user live feedback these calls need to run simultaneously and "call 2" needs to call itself (recursive) to poll for changes.

I have the Controllers and the methods and everything works just fine, just not at the SAME time. Is it a soft lock on the database or is it something else?

Btw I am aware of the "async: true" setting for the ajax call.

[edit] It looks like Magento is preventing me from executing two controllers at the same time. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out.

All I had to do was set:

```
session_write_close();
```

In front of the method that started the import and I could start polling with a second AJAX call!

This is probably frowned upon, but it works